# View count class name thresholds

Tags: discussion, views, question-lists

Over on StackOverflow there was a [recent meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284403/2065702) about how comment colors are applied.

When looking through the CSS of a question list, I noticed the same class names are applied to the views of a question when they're in a list. Upon [asking for clarification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284403/what-is-a-cool-comment/284404?noredirect=1#comment147328_284404), animuson said

> The views counts do get colored too, based on completely different numbers though.

Judging from [this page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) it seems they're applied because of *view count*, not *vote count* like comments.

So what are the view count thresholds that determine which class the view count gets?

Comment: *Thresholds* might be a better term than *breakpoints*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a bunch of question lists I looked at, the thresholds seem to be at the following view counts:

**1-999:** "cool" class
**1k–9,999:** "warm" class
**10k–99,999:** "hot" class
**100k+:** "supernova" class